# Button with a Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup, caliburn.micro

I have a button, when user put the mouse over the element I want to show a Popup. 
Inside this Popup, contains buttons that user can click.
All of it inside of a Itemscontrol.

I'm already showing the popup when user put the mouse over button, but I don't know how to:

1) Hide popup if the user doesn't "focus" on  the popup.

2) If user focus on popup, after focused in button, the popup has to stay opened

My code now:

```
 <Button x:Name="MyButton" MouseEnter="LabelShift_MouseDown"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" >
        <Grid MaxHeight="80">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" >
                <TextBlock Name="Identifier" FontSize="26" Margin="10,10,10,10" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Identifier}"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Name="Value" FontSize="24" Margin="10,10,10,10" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat='C'}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">

                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                        Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">

                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                                        KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                        Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>


<Popup x:Name="ToolTip" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyButton}"  StaysOpen="True" Placement="Bottom" Height="Auto" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyButton}" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="#909090" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" >
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <!-- Content/Elements-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
<Popup.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">

        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ToolTip"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                                                                        KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                                                        Value="True" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

</Popup.Triggers>
```

Comment: ToolTip is not a good name for this custom mouse enter given there is a standard ToolTip

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to achieve drop down functionality. The reason I'm sharing this is because:

a) It inherits the ToggleButton, providing all the functionality we need.

b) Little code.

c) It works!

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Controls
{
    public class DropDownButton : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DropDown", typeof(ContextMenu), typeof(DropDownButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public ContextMenu DropDown
        {
            get
            {
                return (ContextMenu)GetValue(DropDownProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(DropDownProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public DropDownButton()
        {
            // Bind the ToogleButton.IsChecked property to the drop-down's IsOpen property 
            Binding binding = new Binding("DropDown.IsOpen");
            binding.Source = this;
            this.SetBinding(IsCheckedProperty, binding);
        }

        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            if (DropDown != null)
            {
                //If there is a drop-down assigned to this button, then position and display it 
                DropDown.PlacementTarget = this;
                DropDown.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
                DropDown.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to use a UserControl in place of the ContextMenu, you can simply add a new property to said control called IsOpen, and, following same logic as above sample, can use bindings to show the UserControl only when the ToggleButton is checked.

Comment: How does this behave if the user opens the drop down, then clicks on the button to close it? I found `ToggleButton` behaved weirdly in that case, so I ended up using a normal button bound to a simple `OpenCommand`, and disabling the button while `IsOpen`

Comment: You'd want to remove the binding. Then on click, if it's open, close it. If it's closed, open it. `if (DropDown != null && DropDown.IsOpen) DropDown.IsOpen = false; else if (DropDown != null & DropDown.IsClosed) DropDown.IsOpen = true;`. Checking if the ToggleButton is checked is an option, too.

Comment: So you're just using a button for the visuals.

Comment: Either/or. I found the ToggleButton was more convenient for my case.

Comment: Trouble is, I think this dude wants it to open on hover, not click. I couldn't make too much sense out of his requirements. Hover popups enrage me, but I didn't feel like arguing with him about it. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @ThyArtIsCode thanks for the code. Your code could work to show the popup if the user hover the button (changing click event to mouseenter), but the main problem it's the control to keep opened the popup if the user its with the mouse on it (because there is a button inside of it) and hide the popup if the user leaves the button OR leaves the popup